# Is something broken about the “necromancer” badge?

Tags: bug, badges

Necromancer badge is for good answers to old questions. I was looking at who won it lately:
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer
None of the dates are right. It says Ozymandias most recently earned it on October 28. But the link is to an answer Ozzy wrote on Feb 17, 2017! I looked through the others. They all have wrong dates.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or is this a bug in the exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Badges are awarded when all the conditions are met.

If the answer was posted on Feb 17 2017 but the conditions were met on Oct 28, in this case

> Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more.

then Oct 28 is the date in which the badge is awarded.

I assume the fifth upvote was given on Oct 28.

Comment: I hadn’t thought about the votes changing the time.